# What are the sidequest I can do before Mt. Bur-Omisace?

Tags: final-fantasy-12

I am leaving for Mt. Bur-Omisace. I haven't played any side quest except 5 hunts from Sandsea. What are the side quests  I have missed and where can I find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before Mt. Bur-Omisace you should be able to:

- Complete ~15 mark hunts (from task board in Sandsea as well as from Montblanc in the Clan Hall in Rabanastre)
- Obtain 4 optional espers:

  - Adrammelech (Zertinan Caverns/Athroza Quicksands)
  - Zalera (Barheim Passage/Terminus No. 7)
  - Cuchulainn (Garamsythe Waterway/No. 1 Cloaca)
  - Exodus (Mosphoran Highwaste/Empyrean Seat)
- Obtain the Zodiac Spear from the Necrohol of Nabudis (assuming you did not open any of the chests that prevent the spear from spawning)

Comment: +1... Abt that Zodiac spear i opened the chests... I just now learned abt that spear. Is the second method of obtaining the Zodiac spear is easy? At what part of story line will i able to get  that.

Comment: There is a chest in Henne Mines that has a 0.001% (1/1000) chance to give a Zodiac Spear if you open it with the Diamond Armlet equipped. You have to complete a few higher level mark hunts and have captured 10+ espers to get into the area with the chest. If you're set on having this spear, you should probably restart your game and not open the "forbidden" chests as the 2nd chance to get the spear is far from guaranteed.

Comment: I had a bit of a math fail there. The above comment should read 0.1%, not 0.001% for the chance to get the Zodiac Spear from the chest in Henne Mines.

Comment: I would like to add that in *Final Fantasy XII: The Zodiac Age* the Zodiac Spear can be brought from as a reward for doing the Hunt Club in the  Phon Coast